# How to reference another column in another table when writing a trigger?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have a table `EmpSalary` which has a column `salaryPaid`, the current salary of the employee and a table `Emp` which has a column `baseSalary`, the lowest salary available for that employee's job. I want to write a trigger for the `EmpSalary` table that does some calculation to ensure the employee is being paid within a certain percent range(not 70% more than `baseSalary` of that employee's job). 


I have the calculations worked out on paper but I'm not sure how to reference the `Emp` table when I'm writing a trigger on the `EmpSalary` table?

`CREATE TRIGGER Check_Salary
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON EmpSalary
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    v_salary;
    v_baseSalary;
    ...
BEGIN
    v_salary := old.salaryPaid
    v_baseSalary := Emp.baseSalary
    ...
END;
/`

any insight would be great! Trying to study for a big exam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a SELECT in a trigger, as long as the table you're SELECTing data from isn't the one on which the trigger is defined. In this case you can SELECT the data from EMP:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Check_Salary
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON EmpSalary
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    v_salary      NUMBER;
    v_baseSalary  NUMBER;
    ...
BEGIN
    v_salary := old.salaryPaid;

    SELECT BASESALARY
      INTO v_baseSalary
      FROM EMP
      WHERE EMP.some_key_column = :old.some_key_column;

    ...
END;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the tip. :)